# Declare Dynamic Date Table Name for Query Reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am simply trying to research/obtain logic for how to dynamically (I.e. GETDATE() function) call tables which are created with date stamps.

For example, I have tables in the database listed as such:

- [dbo].[CLAIM_01.01.2018]
- [dbo].[CLAIM_01.15.2018]
- [dbo].[CLAIM_01.31.2018]

The logic I am thinking of would behave similar to that of setting a variable for a data element in a table (I.e. SET @IMPORT_DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))

Instead I would like to write a declare statement that would scan the database for a table name based on date stamp parameters. In other words, I am looking for logic that would reference the most RECENT/MAX date of the table generation (in the above examples, 1/31/2018)

Please let me know if I can/should provide greater specificity for this request.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Why do you have such painful table names? This should be a column in your table. Naming objects with the date as part of the name is not a good practice. Although it does make sense in some data cubes or perhaps very rarely in a historical table.

Comment: To do what you are describing requires dynamic sql and some string manipulation. You have to first turn that name into a date, then figure out which date is the most recent and then piece together this naming convention again.

Comment: Sean is 100% correct.  However, it you must archive data like this, why not have a table called CLAIM_Current and offload/archive as necessary

Comment: I have a hunch OP deals with data similar to mine, and these claims have different columns for each (hence why they are not in one table). Maybe the solution is to create a table with an actual date field that you can query, and in the row also have the table name itself. It's not an easy solution and I've been trying to come up with a better one for a year now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. Select the user tables of the database and convert the suffix to a date.

```
DECLARE @maxTable VARCHAR(255)
SET @maxTable = (
    SELECT TOP (1) name
    FROM (
        SELECT  name
            ,   DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(name,4), SUBSTRING(name, 7, 2), SUBSTRING(name, 10, 2)) AS dTable
        FROM    sys.tables WHERE type = 'U'
        ) AS sub
    ORDER BY sub.dTable DESC)

SELECT @maxTable
```

**Result**

```
CLAIM_01.31.2018
```

Comment: This helped! Thank you Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep this schema, you can select for a pattern in `sys.tables`, like:

```
DECLARE @IMPORT_DATE nvarchar(10) = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 4)
SELECT schemas.name + '.' + tables.name 
FROM sys.tables INNER JOIN sys.schemas 
ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id 
WHERE tables.name LIKE '%' + @IMPORT_DATE + '%'
```

That being said, wouldn't it make more sense to have a date field in a single, static CLAIM table?